# Apache NiFi/Hive - store merged tweets in HDFS, create table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, apache-nifi

I want to create a following workflow:

1.Fetch tweets using GetTwitter processor.

2. Merge tweets in a bigger file using MergeContent process.
3. Store merged files in HDFS.
4. On the hadoop/hive side I want to create an external table based on these tweets.

There are examples how to do this but what I am missing is how to configure MergeContent processor: what to set as header,footer and demarcator.
And what to use on on hive side as separator so thatit will split merged tweets in rows.
Hope I described myself clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MergeContent processor in binary mode does the job fine. No need for header,footer and demarcator.